# ExponentialBackoff job Reload function Error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, google-bigquery, exponential-backoff

I'm getting the following fatal error when running the php script below:

Waiting for job to complete

```
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method 
Google\Cloud\BigQuery\CopyJobConfiguration::*reload()*
 in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test.php:53 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: 
 {closure}() #1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud/src/Core/ExponentialBackoff.php(74):
 call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array) #2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test.php(58):
 Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff->execute(Object(Closure)) #3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test.php(36): 
 copy_table('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee') #4 {main} thrown in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test.php on line 54**
```

.

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer

require "vendor/autoload.php";  

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;
use Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff;

$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/.ssh/xxx.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

# Your Google Cloud Platform project stuff
$projectId = 'aaaa';
$datasetIdin = 'bbbb';
$datasetIdout = 'cccc';
$tableIdin = "dddd";
$tableIdout = "eeee";

$gcloud = new ServiceBuilder([ 
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

copy_table($projectId, $datasetIdin, $datasetIdout, $tableIdin, $tableIdout);

function copy_table($projectId, $datasetIdin, $datasetIdout, $tableIdin, $tableIdout)
{
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $datasetin = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetIdin);
    $datasetout = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetIdout);
    $sourceTable = $datasetin->table($tableIdin);
    $destinationTable = $datasetout->table($tableIdout);
    $job = $sourceTable->copy($destinationTable);

    // poll the job until it is complete
    $backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);
    $backoff->execute(function () use ($job) {
        print('Waiting for job to complete' . PHP_EOL);
        $job->reload();
        if (!$job->isComplete()) {
            throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
        }
    });
    // check if the job has errors
    if (isset($job->info()['status']['errorResult'])) {
        $error = $job->info()['status']['errorResult']['message'];
        printf('Error running job: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error);
    } else {
        print('Table copied successfully' . PHP_EOL);
    }

echo "table copied"; 
}

?>
```

It looks as 'though the appropriate class has not been loaded? The composer.json I am using is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.47.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why I'm hitting this error? Thanks!

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is off in your approach.

```
$job = $sourceTable->copy($destinationTable);
```

this doesn't return a Job.

Returns a copy **job configuration** to be passed to either `Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Table::runJob()` or `Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Table::startJob()`.

so you further need to add code to pass this conf to the above functions.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.47.0/bigquery/table?method=copy

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the php function (or very close to it) at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#copy-table, so I can't see what other code I need to add?

Comment: on every page where the tutorial is off, you can signal it on the feedback page, you can find the link in the top of the page. you need to add something like `$jobConfig = $sourceTable->copy($destinationTable);$job = $table->startJob($jobConfig);`

Comment: I have just left feedback! Thanks @Pentiom10! A further question - what does the variable $table in $job = $table->startJob($jobConfig); refer to? Must that be a pre-declared variable?

Comment: I think it's just an encapsulation of a method under table entity it can be your `$sourceTable`, I don't have a shell to test out, but try it out.